# How to call contract public variable using web3py?

Tags: python, solidity, web3py

I tried to call solidity smart contract public variable using python web3.
But when I called, it didn't work and showed the error: 500 (Internal Server Error).

Code summary is like this:

- smart contract part:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
...
contract TestNFT is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable, Pausable {
...
   mapping(uint => bool) public locked;
...
}
```

- python code:

`fashionItemAddress` and `abi` are from at first line of this code and they are working well.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def sendTxHashUndress(request):
    transaction_hash = request.POST["transaction_hash"]

    INFURA_URL = "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/9eda0366d20f4627860299a5ac514808"
    web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(INFURA_URL))
    fContract = web3.eth.contract(fashionItemAddress, abi=ABI)
    print(fContract, '2222222222222')
    print(fContract.call().locked(), '==============')
    try:
        receiptments = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(transaction_hash, 120, 0.1)
        print("receiptments", receiptments.status)
        if receiptments.status == 1:
            return _undressIcongirl(request)

        return JsonResponse({'result': 'failed_transaction'})
    except Exception as error:
        print(str(error))
        return JsonResponse({'result': str(error)})
```

the result in console is like this:

```
0xe0ffc7d34f98803e7744cc587f80df19e93a010a760f7af1253c1405ff2faded 11111111
<web3._utils.datatypes.Contract object at 0x0000024679478A60> 2222222222222
[28/Jun/2022 18:47:53] "POST /api/sendTxHashUndress HTTP/1.1" 500 145
```

[image]

I think the problem is to get `fContract`. If not, I am not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying as several times and checking code deeply, I never tried to send param in `locked()` function.

I mean I have to send param as `token_id` in `locked(token_id)` like this.

This works for me and this was solved.